# Runtime Exception - Repository not found

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php

With and old laravel 5.5 project i am having this problem.

A package I was using has been removed from github and when i try `composer install` I get:

```
  [RuntimeException]                                                                                          
  Failed to execute git clone --mirror 'https://***:***@github.com/dangeroustry/FattureCloud.git' '/home/mir  
  co/.cache/composer/vcs/https---github.com-dangeroustry-FattureCloud.git/'                                   
                                                                                                              
  Cloning into bare repository '/home/username/.cache/composer/vcs/https---github.com-dangeroustry-FattureCloud  
  .git'...                                                                                                    
  remote: Repository not found.                                                                               
  fatal: repository 'https://github.com/dangeroustry/FattureCloud.git/' not found
```

So I tried to remove this package with `composer remove vendor/package` but I can't remove it.
When i run the command

```
composer remove vendor/kiboko/fatture-cloud-laravel/
```

I get this error

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                                                
  The "https://api.github.com/repos/dangeroustry/FattureCloud/zipball/4c4133a965985c1b8c6e41bbfb47ec912a167681" file could not be downlo  
  aded (HTTP/2 404 )
```

How to solve this loop?

Comment: The `vendor` in `composer remove vendor/package` is the vendor name, not a folder, try removing  `vendor/` from your `composer remove vendor/kiboko/fatture-cloud-laravel`, so it is `composer remove kiboko/fatture-cloud-laravel`

Comment: Thank you @brombeer. It works but the repository section still there. I tried `composer config --unset repositories.dangeroustry/FattureCloud` but the repository section still there.

Comment: If I try `composer install` after the package is removed I get this `Script php artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 1` `Undefined index: name in PackageManifest.php line 120`